# Only require comment approval when an image is attached

Tags: comments

I am working on a project that allows user commenting without administrator approval if they post only text; however, if the user decides to attach an image to their comment, the comment should require approval first before being published. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: I think you could do this in Rules (http://drupal.org/project/rules) – act on a new comment being saved and then use a condition where the content contains the string `<img`, then set the status to unpublished and send an email or something.

Comment: @CharlieS I set up a text comparison condition in Rules and set "<img" (without quotes) as the matching text. It works if I enter "<img" as plain text, but if I upload an image it does not work.

Comment: It's probably comparing the text (whatever was inputted after it's been run through a `check_plain()` filter) as opposed to the raw data. See if there's a way to check the raw, unfiltered input.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using the [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom) module.

In Mollom's configuration, you can enable spam filtering and set up your own blacklist terms for the spam filter. I created blacklist terms for **<img** and **"media-image"** (TinyMCE's encoded image class). Then I told Mollom to "Retain the post for manual moderation" if it gets detected as spam.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module to do this by using the [hook_comment_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) hook. If your module name is playx, then try this code:

```
function playx_comment_presave($comment) {
  if(strstr($comment->comment_body[$comment->language][0]['value'], '<img')){
   $comment->status = 0;
 }
```